# Do non-English words increase the probability of receiving downvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, english

I'm a .NET developer from Argentina, and, as you **may could** (*) know, our main language is Spanish. In some of my questions, I have included code with some words in my language, because you all know how hard it is to find every occurrence of a variable, a method, a name of a control, etc.

Do I have translate every word to English, or is such translation irrelevant? I think that Spanish is a language that uses the same alphabet as English, but what about Russian, Chinese, etc.?  Must we adapt everything to English to make users happier?

For example:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

is the same for you as:

```
public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

is to me.

Comment: It increases chances of not being understood.

Comment: `nombre` is understandable to me and the only Spanish I know is what I picked up 40 years ago on family holidays to Spain and from watching Westerns that had Mexican characters.

Comment: Yes, I know that some words in spanish could be readable, but my question wants to know how predisposes the users this kind of things. Looking the answers, I think that is better to take this effort.

Comment: You would need to ask psychologists and linguists about predisposition.

Comment: Yes, it does. But normally if some [editor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?filter=all&tab=editors) who knows Spanish and English sees your post, they edit it and make it English.

Comment: The fact that you refuse to follow the framework design guidelines (lower case property names???) irks me more than your moonspeak.

Comment: It's all convention. People who see "name" as identifier name instinctively know it's a string. The same as "id" must be int and "value" can be anything.

Comment: With your example I experimented a little confusion, because "nombre" means "number" in French ;)

Comment: Given the strange things my coworkers have come up with to name their functions, I couldn't even figure out which word in the sample you provided wasn't in English.

Comment: the word was "nombre"... which means name =s

Comment: I've answered questions that had code I think it was in Spanish (or Portuguese, or something, as you can tell I do not speak these languages). It doesn't bother me.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote for non-english, but I am less likely to answer, as with non-english names its harder to understand complex code.  I think you'll get more and better answers in english.

Comment: @ChrisF: Well, lucky you, I learned English and German (and promptly forgot the latter) so *nombre* looks like *number* to me.

Comment: I find the mixing of English keywords with non-English identifiers quite ugly. That's because I *never* use Italian names, not even in my private code, although I'm Italian. The equivalent of `public string name = {get; set}` in Italian *ought to be* `pubblico stringa nome = {ottieni; imposta}` while `public string nome = {get; set}` is *not* "Italian code", it only increases confusion because now to understand the underlying intention of the code you have to speak two languages instead of one.

Comment: Personally, I think localized variable names don't even belong in code in the first place. In case you ever need to outsource or hire someone whose primary language isn't spanish :D But I would never downvote. But I am less likely to answer if it takes too much effort to understand the question.

Comment: @Bakuriu You won't translate `public` nor `string` anyway, even if you localize all your code, those beings language constructs. So localized code would look like a mismatch of english-[insert language here] words, and that's why I tend to translate everything to enligsh, for cohesion and omogeneity

Comment: I don't understand how "you all know how hard it is to find every occurrence of a variable, a method, a name of a control, etc."
Seriously, it's very easy. Every normal text editor has a "search and replace" function, and IDEs have "refactor" functions, which change the name in multiple files at once. How exactly is that hard?

Comment: @BartekMaraszek it is really annoying to have to do _all_ that work in order to just ask a question. Besides that, I think it should be a **fact** that people will tend to ignore it - I even tend to do that myself, to be honest. It won't deserve a downvote (I hope!) but if you can translate them it would be better.

Comment: It can make understanding the question a lot more difficult, thus reducing your potential answering audience. Here's an example that I saw a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626198/sql-sum-problems

Comment: Yes, we must adapt everything to English. English is a second language to me, but I would probably never even consider posting with anything but English names, and strings. Every introductory programming course teaches that program code is a form of communication, not with the computer but with humans who will read it, and how important well-chosen names are for understanding. If I had code with non-English names, changing them would be one of the first things I'd do to make my question understandable. Right after preparing the self-contained, minimal example that still shows the problem.

Comment: I think you mainly get downvotes when the English is garbled, or when foreign variable/method names are not translated where their meaning is significant.  (I'm much more likely to downvote someone who formats their code poorly, miscapitalizes variable names, etc.  And heaven help the poor soul who fails to check relevant return codes -- they're read the riot act.)

Comment: Downvotes for unintelligible English?  It's certainly temping! *can u help plz?  code dont wurk!*

Comment: I am ALWAYS anoyed by Excel when I can't use `IF(...)` because MS localized those functions and I need to use `WENN(...)` (German for if)...

Comment: It really strikes me no one mentioned our Argentinian ego shouting in `you all should know, our main language is Spanish` :)

Comment: was not my intention... my english has some mistakes. Luckly exists Messi to show to all the world that not all the argentinians are how you think. I apologize for this and I will correct it right now.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

No, you don't have to translate code into English.  An identifier is an identifier.

That said, additional clarifying comments in English would be nice, since we can't read the word meanings of the identifiers.

I haven't seen a lot of downvotes on questions with non-English code, *if* the question itself is clearly written in English.

If you do paste code with identifiers in languages like Chinese (that don't use [Roman characters](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_alphabet)), it *will* make it very difficult for us to read the code and understand what it does.

Comment: thanks for your help!... I think that we all should take care about what could be readable in order to get more accurate answers.

Comment: Since well named identifiers are part of "self-documenting" some people might choose not to answer a question if they cannot understand the language. I wouldn't say that this would cause DV's though.

Comment: If the meaning of the identifier is irrelevant to the question, then the language should be irrelevant. If it's a complex question and the meaning of identifiers would help understand the question, then you should consider translating.

Comment: What about French C++ code? ;)

Comment: As a native Dutch speaker, I was confused about a question on how to work with a "map". Only when I realized the OP was Dutch as well, I could mentally translate it to "folder" and it suddenly made sense.

Comment: If the poster has time to write clarifying comments in English, why not change the identifiers instead? (Needlessly obscure code "fixed" with comments is one of my pet peeves.)

Comment: I would say that the *more complex* the code is, the harder it will be to understand if it isn't in a language the reader can understand (i.e. English). `nombre`? Feh, it's an identifier; foo, bar, baz, qux.  If the question text explains that the function shown has some intended meaning I can probably figure it out, but if its 35+ lines of Greek with no accompanying translation, it's going to be *much* harder: there's no longer the implicit mapping of words to ideas.  So I'd say it's a problem that only rears its head when the *amount* of code exceeds five to seven identifiers.

Answer (score 90):

Lets have an example. You are looking at a function for checking if somebody was of legal age when s/he bought that drink. It's not working, or you would not be here.

In English:

```
static bool WasOfLegalAgeAtTheTimeOfPurchase(Person p, Date purchaseDate, Drink d)
{
   return (p.BirthDate + purchaseDate) > d.RequiredLegalAge;
}
```

Easy. You mixed that up. It should have read `purchaseDate - BirthDate`. No brainer, you've got 5 answers in three minutes fighting for rep.

Now let's try this again when I speak Huffnockese and use it in my naming:

```
static bool FraNuklEkorAffDeeta(Ramulk r, Date jobingaTor, Granu g)
{
   return (r.Protpork + jobingaTor) > g.KnabMoDeeta;
}
```

Okay. Breathe. Think. There must be sense in it. Lets try to decipher it. At this point, you lost me. I'm here to help people with programming problems, not to solve riddles in my spare time. I could buy a magazine full of riddles if I wanted and I decided not to.

The base line is: use whatever naming you like best. However, if you need help, it's best to make it as easy as possible to answer you. And Huffnockese makes it harder. Any other language will do so as well. I will certainly not downvote you, but you will lose my answer. And in the end, you are asking questions to get answers, not votes.

Sidenote, I'm not a native speaker. English is a foreign language for me as well. But it makes communicating so much easier, that it's worth it :)

Comment: It's past time Huffnockese was made mandatory in kindergarten.

Comment: +1 When questions ask "Why doesn't this work", foreign code makes it *so* much harder to figure it out. Any code for debugging should be in english.

Comment: I would say, English should be `Lingua Franca`for programming in order to accelerate the code review. It's anyway more advantageous.

Comment: On the other hand, this question would be closed as "typo" if expressed in English; that being said I completely agree with you, if I cannot figure out the code I'll just move on.

Comment: And that Huffnockese manner of starting variable and function names from big letter, brrrr... ;)

Comment: out of sheer curiosity: you made that language up as you were typing? I am asking because `Deeta` is used twice at the right place.

Comment: @Woj yes, that's totally made up. But it had to made some sense, languages aren't exactly random characters. Just enough so you *could* make sense of it, if you invested an unproportional amount of time.

Comment: I love this answer. Still laughing after the fourth read.

Comment: If the names are germane to the conversation, if it was "why doens't this compile and was using generics or something then you don't care what the names are."

Comment: I'm starting a proposal on Area 51 for stackoverflow in Huffnockese.  Please vote for it!  We welcome all Huffnokians!

Answer (score 22):

Having the code in a question be in another language makes that code harder to understand.  Whether this effect is enough to push the question past the line of "I have to work to try to understand it but I can manage" into "I just can't understand this" is of course going to depend on the question, how complex it is, how well everything else in the question is presented, etc.

So do you *have* to translate it?  No.

Does it make the question better to translate it?  Yes.

Will your question be answerable without you translating it?  Maybe.

To answer your literal question of whether or not it increases the probability of downvotes, yes, it does.  The question is less likely to be understood by as many people, and people that don't understand it are going to be more likely to downvote it.  The degree of this effect is of course going to vary widely based on the specifics.

Comment: I think, if someone read code it's the same whether that code contains identifiers in spanish, german or english, code is code, there is just a way to declare a string and that's `String` <identifier> and not `Cadena` or `Kette`, so I think, we all can understand what a code does without knowing what an identifier means. Furthermore we have great online dictionaries if we are curious enough. Just think, an algorithm is like a recipe with pictures and each Step says with a picture how we must proceed and its sequence, so it's the same to read `butter`, `mantequilla`, `Beurre` or `Burro`.Regards

Comment: @Gödel77: I politely disagree. On the OP's simple example it matters little; however when you are faced with more than just a couple lines of code trying to figure out how each part relate to the other *and* the OP's question (talking about names, but I see no *name* in the code!), then appropriately named identifiers help a lot.

Comment: Ok Matthieu, There could be Problems in case of an Interface, I agree but in implementation? I don't think so. Kind Regards

Comment: @Gödel77 It sounds like you haven't spent much time at all trying to understand what other people's code does, or why it doesn't work in particular.  Meaningful identifier names are *hugely* important when it comes to making code understandable.

Comment: @Servy As explained, in an Interface is disadvantageous because there is no more code than declaration, then you're right but in implementation is imho clearer.I haven't asserted identifiers in English or n english are better or not, I've said,code can be understandable if you know structures(data, control, loops...) in each language but I must admit, I'm not objective cause my daily routine runs in spanish, german and english (I have had to review code in those 3 Languages), perhaps I have the habit to go to online dictionary. Excuse me If I didn't express it right. Kind Regards

Comment: *Does it make the question better to translate it?* It depends. In the specific example it does not make any difference at all. Using `Nombre` is as good or as bad as using `XYZ` or `Foo` or `Baz`.

Comment: @nico In the given example isn't actually a question.  Nothing is being asked of the code, it has no problems, etc.  In general with quite a lot of questions the semantic meaning of the code is relevant.  Just because you can manage to answer the question without having meaningful variable names doesn't mean that it's not better to have them.

Comment: @Servy: again, it depends on the question. If you are able to understand a question with a variable named `XYZ` (which is not an English word) you will be able to understand it also if the name of the variable is `Nombre` or `Nome` or `qazxsw`.

Comment: @nico Yes, as I've said, it may indeed be possible to understand the question without having meaningful variable names.  Just because it's *possible* to understand the question doesn't change the fact that its preferable to have meaningful variable names.  It's better, even if its "good enough" without it.

Answer (score 13):

It's not a necessity to translate everything to English. But you give yourself a better chance of getting the answers you're looking for by making your questions as clear and easy to read as possible. And since most people on this site understand English, I think it's in your own best interest to translate as much as you can.

I certainly wouldn't downvote a question just because it contains a few non-English words. And if a question looks really interesting, and it's something I can answer, a few identifiers in Spanish won't stop me. But the barrier is slightly higher because the question is harder for me to read and understand.

One aspect I wanted to mention that the other answers didn't directly address: Comments! If the code contains comments in a language I don't understand, that bothers me more than identifiers. The premise is that posted code is the minimum needed for me to reproduce and *understand* the issue. So if the posted code contains comments, I can assume that the poster considered these comments critical for my understanding of the code. But if they're in a language I don't speak, they're really just a distraction and waste of space. So there's an inherent contradiction in this case. Either the comments need to be understandable to the reader, or they should not be there at all.

So my point of view is that non-English comments should be frowned upon. Non-English identifiers are somewhat undesirable, but not a big deal if the rest of the question is clear, and the code is still understandable.

Comment: I think your point of view is totally right. Sometimes the comments point you critical parts of the code and if you can't understand it, becomes something that bother. Is interesting what you said! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I think that the following quote from [Jerry Maguire movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116695/) is applicable here:

### "Help *us* help *you*"

Most of us do not come to this site just looking for a chance to downvote something.  We genuinely (and/or in a pursuit of reputation growth) want to help.  So whatever you can do to make this task *easier* for us will be ultimately beneficial to you.

If you feel that whatever is there in your mother tongue is immaterial for the problem at hand - leave them (or even better - remove them).

If any of such information would help us to *understand your situation better*, then go ahead and invest your time and effort into a translation. {Just be aware that Google Translate is still a work in progress).