# Should I edit a question's code to translate non-English words?

Tags: discussion, edits, languages

I recently bumped into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080753/how-to-create-a-searchbar-with-javascript#38080753) question and I saw that the user has Spanish names for variables and etc. like that:

```
var textbuscar = document.getElementById("buscar");
```

Being non-English speaker I still believe that using native (non-English) language (where not necessary) is hurting readability and understanding of code.

Thus I am concerned - should I provide (if I can) an edit where I will replace all local-language variables and stuff with English ones **if** I find the usage of those excessive?

```
var textSearch = document.getElementById("search");
```

Comment: Related: [Do non-English words increase the probability of receiving downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes)

Comment: It's the `id` of an element. If you wouldn't rename a variable named `x`, why rename an element named `buscar` (or variable named `textbuscar`)? You don't need to know the meaning of the word to see whether it matches usage elsewhere in the code. Also, language has nothing to do with race, so you might consider rephrasing that middle paragraph.

Comment: @paul in that case I am not, but what about this code `static bool FraNuklEkorAffDeeta(Ramulk r, Date jobingaTor, Granu g)
{
   return (r.Protpork + jobingaTor) > g.KnabMoDeeta;
}` ? I don`t think thats readable

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/1767412, unless someone wants to argue the code is not "content" - which I think it is.

Comment: @billynoah see [this highly upvoted comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content#comment211024_297680).

Comment: @Glorfindel - thanks for pointing that out.  The policy seems to be "don't edit" either way, but for different reasons.  Anyway, I believe we're in agreeance - don't edit

Comment: and for what it's worth, there's no way I'm voting to close or flagging a question because of non-english variable names.  most variable names hardly resemble english anyway

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, in general: *don't edit code*, neither in questions nor in answers. Proper formatting is probably the only exception (and Python code is an exception to *that* exception). By editing code snippets, especially when it comes to renaming variables, the resulting code is almost guaranteed *not* to work in the context of the OP's project.

If someone doesn't understand why a variable is named like it is, and it is necessary for creating a good answer, he/she can always leave a comment.

But you are right, naming variables in English is 100% better. To me (native Dutch speaker) it even looks silly, English reserved words of the programming language intermingled with Dutch variable names.

Comment: `var worterSuchen = document.getElementById("suchen")` being a russian-speaking that reads even funnier than you may think

Comment: I almost can't stress this enough. Often times, when editing code, the little small fixes you do almost instinctively as a programmer might end up completly invalidating the question or cancelling out some small but significant detail that the entire problem case hinges upon.

Answer (score 7):

You should edit *your* code samples to either use sensible English words in variable/method names or (if not important to question) use generic one-two letter names.

You should not edit code in other posts - edits without full edit privileges will likely be rejected, edits with full edit privileges likely be frowned upon. Comment on the post instead if you find that names distracting from the question.

Note: If you know that names are offensive - edit is ok - make sure to have good edit summary. If OP rolls back such edit (edit war starts) - flag such post.