# Code in non-English languages

Tags: discussion, code, languages

What is the consensus when someone gives a post in English, but their code is clearly in a different language?

Should these posts be flagged?

(Before anyone criticizes me of non-inclusivity, I am an immigrant, English is my third language, I have a thick accent in real life, and I would prefer all posts within English Stack Overflow to be 100% in English.)

Comment: There's only so much about code that can be in different languages... What difference does it make if a variable name is `pasos` instead of `steps`, or something else in another language? The compiler doesn't care about the identifier you use, just that you spell it right every time. As long as the description of the code is in English and the question is clear and in English, I can't see how non-english code makes anything harder to deal with.

Comment: From a software engfineering eprspective, tracing code whose variables you can understand is much easier than tracing code whose variable names are jibberish to you. Which is particularily relevant for words in foreign languages whose names can be similar to one another or words in English.

Comment: People already give variable names of `i` and `x`, etc, which are also just gibberish. Being a foreign language is a moot point.

Comment: If the code is confusing enough that the variable names are a problem, the person probably has provided too much code and should make an MCVE. This is also an issue independent of it being in another language.

Comment: See also: [*How to treat English questions which have code in a foreign language?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194059/242059) (Meta.SE dupl\*cate); [*Should I edit a question's code to translate non-English words?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327021/2751851)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Comment: Given Goole translate, attempting to translate actual code into English is likely to result in ummm 'issues'.  Leave the code alone, just as the OP tested it:)    LIke @DavyM comments above, a huge, and much to large, set of posters seem unable to write readable code anyway and seem to think that single-letter var names are mandated by the compiler/interpeter language used:(