# Would you vote down question because of non-english identifiers in code?

Tags: discussion

Would you vote down question because of non-English identifiers in code? I'm not talking about trivial code here like `int korvkiosk(int a, b) { if(a>b) return a; else return b; }`, but code that is fairly complex and it's pretty hard to understand what the code does, and where English identifiers and printouts would help a lot.

Code example:

```
void obter_ingresso_normal(int id) {
  struct Usuarios usuario;
  usuario.comprado = 0;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&turno);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&entrada);
  printf("------------------- Compra normal! -------------------\n\n");
  if(posicao_ingresso > 0) {
    usuario = reservar_ingresso(id);
    printf("Usuário de número: %d está comprando o ingresso de número: %d\n", usuario.id, usuario.numero_ingresso);
    int compra_completa = completar_compra();
    if(compra_completa) {
      usuario.comprado = 1;
      printf("Usuário de número: %d comprou o ingresso de número: %d\n", usuario.id, usuario.numero_ingresso);
    } else {
      posicao_ingresso++;
      printf("Usuário de número: %d não terminou o cadastro para o ingresso de número: %d\n", usuario.id, usuario.numero_ingresso);
    }
  }
  printf("------------------- Término compra normal! -------------------\n\n");
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&entrada);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&turno);
}
```

Printout example:

```
------------------- Compra em Lote! -------------------

Usuário de número: 499 reservou o ingresso de número: 29
Usuário de número: 499 comprou o ingresso em lote de número: 29
Usuário de número: 441 reservou o ingresso de número: 28
Usuário de número: 441 comprou o ingresso em lote de número: 28
------------------- Término Compra em Lote! -------------------
```

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115757/guarantee-that-i-have-at-least-two-threads-inside-function)

This makes it much harder to understand, and much less useful for (most) other people. Note that I'm talking about code and printouts here. Not when the actual question is in another language.

I'd say this question is different than *[Do non-English words increase the probability of receiving downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes)* because that question is about if it does increase the downvotes. This is about if it is a valid reason to downvote.

Comment: I would probably point the user to [pt.so]! Otherwise, I would ask for a MCVE with easier identifiers.

Comment: I would likely downvote it for being fairly complex even if it were in English, as it's usually a sign of lack of debugging.

Comment: I doubt it is useful for future visitors. That would warrant a down vote.

Comment: Well, cosidering the almost indeciperable garbage regularly served up by the single-letter-var posters, eg: 'p*=2-a[i-2][j-1]-b[l-2][l-1];', I quite look forward to a little non-English culture, and variable names.  As long as the text details in the question are in English, I don't feel any great need to downvote such questions.

Comment: It is merely hard to read, I just skip them if there are too many.  There were once a lot of posts using Polish identifiers, a lot less lately for some reason.  I once joked in a comment that the OP's company was unlikely to ever be bought out by a big American company some day.  Maybe there is some truth to that joke :)